# Restore MongoDB from EFS backup

Tags: mongodb, amazon-efs

I'm going to host MongoDB as a containerized service in AWS ECS with Auto Scaling Group (let the managing of EC2 to ECS, while configuring my service to run only 1 instance)

As ECS manages how a n EC2 instance is assigned to my service, i have decided to use EFS to store MongoDB filesystem.

I have also learned, that from MongoDB supports db restore from "regular - like ext4" filesystem snapshots, so if I snap-shot an ext4 filesystem, I can restore it later and continue to use my MongoDB instance

**Can somebody confirm, does it work with EFS snapshots too, or not?**